# Splitting an array to be input into a Map

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, maps

I am trying to split an array of  names such as "Joe Bloggs" Joe and Bloggs are separate and then can be used in a map where the first name is the key. Here is what I have so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> snames = new HashMap<String, String>();
    int index = -1;
    String[] names = new String[8];
    Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );
    for( int i = 0; i <= names.length; i++ ){
        System.out.println( "Enter student name:" );
        names[ i ] = s.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Please type in the student index you want to view between 0 and 7");
    index = s.nextInt();
    while (index >7 || index <0){
        System.out.println("Please type in a valid index value"); 
        index = s.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("The student with the index of " + index + " is " + names[index]);

    }
}
```

Comment: try it yourself, dont expect someone to write it for you.

Comment: I am wanting ideas, not expecting someone to write it for me.

Comment: What if you have two people with the same first name: Joe Bloggs and Joe Smith. The second one will overwrite the first when you add it to your map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure what you are asking for

```
for (String x : names){
    String[] temp = x.split(" "); // split "Joe Bloggs" to ["Joe", "Bloggs"]
    if (temp.length == 2){
        snames.put(temp[0], temp[1]); // Mapping "Joe" to "Bloggs"
    }
}
```

is that what you want?